# codewithmosh NodeJS course asks me a few times to change my NODE_ENV - doesn't work on windows?

Tags: node.js

I’m studying "code with mosh"'s NodeJs course right now, and trying to update my NODE_ENV enviornment Variable with no success…
every time I update it in the CMD or even Windows PowerShell it seems like it did it, and then nothing happens in the NodeJS Express Demo build in the course.
the question I guess i’m asking, is how do you configure your ENV VARs??

edit:
thank you for your answer, it did change my NODE_ENV. But the morgan middleware still starts for some reason... here is the code:

````
const app = express();
const Joi = require('joi');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const config = require('config');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const logger = require('./logger');

console.log(`NODE_ENV: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
console.log(`app ${app.get('env')}`);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(helmet());

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    console.log('morgan is Enabled');
    app.use(morgan('tiny'));
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The solution you need is quite simple.

First, you need to install Dotenv. You can do this via "npm install dotenv"

Second, you will create a file named ".env" in your project's root directory (same directory as your package.json file)

Third, you will place in the .env file this line of code (don't use the quotes): "NODE_ENV = development"

Note, there are no semi-colons used here.

Here's an example from one of my projects in how I then use it. Note that I do have modules turned on in the latest version of Node so my import statements look different than you may be used to...

```
import express from "express";
import colors from "colors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import morgan from "morgan";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import { notFound, errorHandler } from "./middleware/errorMiddleware.js";

dotenv.config();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

const app = express();

// Middleware
// Only run Morgan in development mode
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
}
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is online...");
});

// Error and 404 handling Middleware
app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`.green.bold));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the value logged to the console by console.log(`app ${app.get('env')}`);

For me, it is "app development"

However, in your code you are testing if it is equal to "development". You likely need to change "development" to "app development".

Or, you can simply change it to the below...

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    console.log('morgan is Enabled');
    app.use(morgan('tiny'));
}
```

The main purpose here is that certain things don't waste resources in production. As such, when you're ready to deploy, you simply change NODE_ENV to "production" in your .env file versus "development" and Morgan will no longer be active.